# Expo App iOS error: when I get to home and then return to the App, the whole page reloads

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

A page on my App shows a bug on iOS: when I am on it, then I get to the iOS home screen, and finally I return to the App, sometimes the WHOLE page reloads: Every variable (e.g. useState variables) gets the initial value and the images are loaded as it was their first load (you can see those disappear for a while). How is this possible? This bug occurs on iOS only.

app.json .dependencies:

```
{
    "@bugsnag/expo": "^49.0.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "~18.0.10",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.8",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.3",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-blur": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.6",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.11",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^12.4.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "^7.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0"
  },
```

Everything I tried helped me to better understand the problem. From what I know, the bug does not depend on the page code (I performed my tests). I deduce that it is a matter of dependencies.

EDIT: I discovered that ANY OTHER screen on the App presents this bug (STILL ON IOS ONLY).

Comment: iOS can remove your app from memory at any time when it is suspended. When you tap the icon it will be relaunched. If it is important that the app returns to the same place then you need to store the app state somewhere and use that on launch

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I solved this by using React.memo() on components that App.js rendered.